# Organizing a list of of strings based on a list of integers c#

Tags: c#, arrays

I have an array of integers organized from greatest to least, however, I want the numerical values to be associated with a name string entered by the user and ordered from greatest to least based on that numerical value.
The array is organized like this:

```
 int[] array = new int[] { diceRoll1, diceRoll2, diceRoll3, diceRoll4, diceRoll5, diceRoll6, diceRoll7, diceRoll8 };
        Array.Sort<int>(array,
                        new Comparison<int>(
                                (i1, i2) => i2.CompareTo(i1)
                        ));
```

The list of strings is entered by the user, diceRoll1 goes with name1, diceRoll2 goes with name2 etc.

```
 string name1 = nameBox1.Text;
 string name2 = nameBox2.Text;
 string name3 = nameBox3.Text;
 string name4 = nameBox4.Text;
 string name5 = nameBox5.Text;
 string name6 = nameBox6.Text;
 string name7 = nameBox7.Text;
 string name8 = nameBox8.Text;
```

Comment: I don't understand, if you have an array of ints, what do strings have to do with it? I see no strings in your code.

Comment: if you have strings that are associated to the ints then it would be best to create a class to hold both then sort a collection of those objects on the int value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are taking the strings from textboxes, you can build the textbox name dynamically by using the numbers. I assume that the int array contains the indexes of the strings from 1 to 8 in the desired order.

```
string[] textArray = intArray
    .Select(i => Controls("nameBox" & array[i]).Text)
    .ToArray();
```

If you simply want the strings in the order `nameBox8` down to `nameBox1`, you can do it like this

```
string[] textArray = Enumerable.Range(0, 8)
    .Select(i => Controls("nameBox" & (8 - i)).Text)
    .ToArray();
```